# Help with Liouville's formula (putting it into "easier words")

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, proof-writing

I am trying to break down Liouville's formula into "my own words" to see if I am fully understanding it. Does the below steps look ok, especially the variable replacements?

I seem to have a lot of gaps in my knowledge and (hopefully if I am correct) will help me to reduce some of those issues.

I would greatly appreciate any advice/help you can offer as I have been struggling with this for a long time.

(also I am not sure what exactly tags to tags this question with)

[Liouville's formula from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_formula#math_2)

**Calculations**

Let $y' = Ay$  where $A$ is a constant matrix, and $y = y(t)$.

Noting that $(det(\Phi(t)))' = Tr(A) \cdot det(\Phi(t))$.

now solving this equation, I can do

$\frac{y'}{y} = A$

taking the definite integral with respect to x on both sides with limits from $t_0$ to $t$

$\int^t_{t_0} \frac{y'}{y}dt = \int^t_{t_0}A dt$

by performing the change of variable $dy = y'dt $ for the left hand side, and converting the limits to match the change, $t, t_0$ becomes $y(t),y(t_0)$ respectively,

$\int^{y(t)}_{y(t_0)} \frac{dy}{y} = \int^t_{t_0}A dt$

$\implies ln(y(t)) - ln(y(t_0)) = \int^t_{t_0}A dt$

$\implies ln(y(t)) = \int^t_{t_0}A dt +ln(y(t_0))$

taking the $e$ of both sides

$\implies e^{ln(y(t))} = e^{\int^t_{t_0}A dt +ln(y(t_0))}$

$\implies y(t) = e^{\int^t_{t_0}A dt}e^{ln(y(t_0))}$

$\implies y(t) = y(t_0)e^{\int^t_{t_0}A dt}$

now replacing the variable $y(t), A$ with $det(\Phi(t))$ and $Tr(A)$ respectively,

$\implies det(\Phi(t)) = det(\Phi(t_0))e^{\int^t_{t_0}Tr(A) dt}$

Now this shows that if $det(\Phi(t_0)) =0$, then $det(\Phi(t)) = 0$ for all $t$

Comment: If $y$ is vector-valued (as suggested by context), then "$y'/y$" is meaningless. (Didn't read any further.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang you are right, missed that. Suppose I make a change, with  $y(t) =  det(\Phi(t))$ and $A =Tr(A)$ from the beginning so the equation $y' = Ay$ is now replaced with $(det(\Phi(t)))' = Tr(A)det(\Phi(t))$. would it work then?

Comment: If $y(t)=\det(\Phi(t))$, then $y$ is scalar-valued, $\Phi$ (a matrix-valued function of specified determinant?) is not uniquely-defined, and I wouldn't know how to interpret $A = \operatorname{Tr}(A)$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang thanks for the answers, turns out I need to take another look at this. But ultimately is $det(\Phi(t)) = det(\Phi(t_0))e^{\int^t_{t_0}Tr(A) dt}$ derived from $det(\Phi(t))' = Tr(A)det(\Phi(t))$?

Comment: It just feels that I am so close to understanding this, I mean it looks like some ODE, which could be solved by separation of the variables

Comment: There are details here I don't understand, but in the hope it's relevant, there's an identity $\det e^A=e^{\operatorname{Tr}A}$ for $n \times n$ matrices.